# Not possible to submit by javascript in Firefox in jquery onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom, submit

In a jquery onclick event I modify the dom and then do a submit it doesn't work in Firefox but works well in Chrome and IE.

```
    function test(){
    $('#b2').remove();
    var form = document.getElementById("123");
    form.submit();
}

$(function() {
    $('#b1').on('click', test);
});​
```

Here there is the minimal test case http://jsfiddle.net/Tjtjv/
Clicking in button test it should load the page http://jsfiddle.net

How can I make it works in Firefox like in Chrome and IE

Comment: How can I make it work in Firefox like in Chrome and IE

Comment: $('#b2').remove(); why are you removing it, try with hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to remove the area with your button? If you don't want that your users does not submit again the form, you should rather disabled the button :

```
$("#b1").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // instead of $("#b2").remove()
```

Comment: I want to do it because there is synchronization with an hiden select list which contains values sent to server after submiting.

Comment: I ended not removing the area where I clicked to avoid the problem on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your fiddle like this and it works on FF.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/Tjtjv/7)

```
function test(){
    $('#bsub').remove();
    var $form = $("#123");
    $form.submit();
    console.log('form submitted');
}

$(function() {
    $('#b1').on('click', test);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is no more my scenario where I try to delete where I have clicked before submiting

Comment: Do you really want to remove the elements from the form? or do you just need to hide them?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by calling function in `Onclick` event of button.

```
 <form id="123" action="http://jsfiddle.net/" >
     <div id="b2" >
     <button id="b1" onclick="test()">test</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tjtjv/3/)

Comment: I can't do it because my example was over simplified but I need to pass parameters in test() method that is computed in my own javascript